# How to match input password and database hash password in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

How to authenticate a user password from a given request in Laravel? How is the password checked against the password hash stored in the database?
**
This is my Controller
**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    function login1(Request $request){
      $username = $request->input('username');
      $password = $request->input('password');

      

      $data = DB::table('users')->where(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])->first();
      if($data == null){
        echo "error";
    
        $notification = array(
                'message' => 'User Does not Exists!',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );
            return back()->with($notification);
      }
else{
    
       
            $request->session()->put('user',$data);
            return redirect('dashboard');
      
      
}
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the password is hashed in the database so you can't query for it ... you would find the user by the 'username' then you could do a hash check for that password and the plaintext you want to check against  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic terms, what you want to do is:

1. Query the `users` table for a user, with the given username.
2. Check whether their hashed password compares the hash of the provided password.

So, you want to **first** query the table for a user with the given username. Then **after** retrieving the user, and **verifying that they exist**, you can then check if the provided password matches the hashed password on the retrieved model.

```php
public function login(Request $request): Response
{
    $user = User::where('username', $request->get('username'));

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
        return back()->with([
            'message' => 'Incorrect username and/or password.',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        ]);
    }

    $request->session()->put('user', $user);

    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

However, there is baked in functionality in Laravel for this, and it's probably simpler to do something like this, depending on your needs:

```
public function login(Request $request): Response
{
  if (!Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->get('username'), 'password' => $request->get('password')]) {
        return back()->with([
            'message' => 'Incorrect username and/or password.',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.html#method_attempt

Answer (score -2):

like this

$encrypted = Crypt::encrypt('password_name_variable');

Comment: passwords aren't encrypted, they are hashed

Comment: He is asking how a provided password from user input can be checked against a hashed password in the database, not how to encrypt a string.